# Finding the minimum distance between all points and the polygon boundary

Tags: r, spatial, spatstat

I would like to find the minimum distance between points and polygon boundary (all points lie inside the polygon). If that is possible, how can I extract the values?, so I can find a correlation between numbers of individuals and the distance from the border.

The polygon is on .SHP format and points on X/Y coordinates.

Any missing information please let me know! Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `spatstat` package has a function `nncross`that finds the nearest neighbour between two sets of point or one set of points and a set of segments.

It is relatively easy to load a set of x/y values to create a spatstat point pattern object: if X and Y are two vectors containing your coordinates, you can create a point pattern object with

```
library(spatstat)
p = ppp(x,y)
```

You need to convert your shp data to spatstat segment pattern object. To do so, you can load the shp file with commands from maptools and than convert into a spatstat object:

```
library(maptools)
shp = readShapeSpatial("yourdata.shp") #read shp file
shp = as.psp(shp) # convert to psp object
```

To calculate your nearest neighbour distance, you have to use nncross

```
nncross(p,shp)
```

Comment: I had no problem creating the .ppp object, but when I tried to transform the .shp file to .psp shows a error that says: Error in as.psp.default(shp) : 
  Unable to interpret x as a line segment pattern                                       Any suggestion?

Comment: there is a doc [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/spatstat/vignettes/shapefiles.pdf) that might help you. There is probably a problem with how maptools recognizes your shp. What is the class() of your data after `readShapeSpatial()` ?

Comment: the class is [1] "SpatialPolygonsDataFrame"

Comment: To some degree this is not a correct answer. The minimum distance between a point and a polyline is not necessarily the one to one of the nodes of the polyline. But, nncross does exactly this: finding (only) the nearest node of the polyline. 
What if I want to know the minimum distance to any point on the polyline?

Comment: Could you please develop ? I don't have this behaviour on my system. If I create a psp line segment using `line = psp(0.25,0.5,0.75,0.5,window=owin(c(0,1),c(0,1)))` and the set of points `pts = ppp((1:9)/10, rep(0.25,length.out=9))`, `nncross(pts,line)` returns 0.25 for all points that have 0.25>=  x-value  >= 0.75.  The order of arguments is important: `nncross(line,pts)` returns the minimum distance between the nodes of the segment and one of the points.

Answer (score 7):

unit square polygon:

```
library(sp)
x = cbind(c(0,1,1,0,0),c(0,0,1,1,0))
pol = SpatialPolygons(list(Polygons(list(Polygon(x)), "ID")))
```

random points in unit square:

```
set.seed(131)
pts = SpatialPoints(cbind(runif(10), runif(10)))
plot(pol)
points(pts, col = 'red')
```

compute distances:

```
library(rgeos)
gDistance(pts, pol, byid = TRUE) # will be 0, all inside
gDistance(pts, as(pol, "SpatialLines"), byid = TRUE) # dist to line
```

add to plot:

```
text(coordinates(pts),
  as.character(
    round(as.vector(gDistance(pts, as(pol, "SpatialLines"), byid = TRUE)), 3)),
pos = 4)
```

read your polygon data from a shapefile into R by using `readOGR` in package `rgdal`

Answer (score 3):

Follow the steps of @xraynaud (slightly modified):

```
library(maptools)
shp = readShapeSpatial("yourdata.shp") #read shp file
W = as.owin(shp) # convert to owin object

library(spatstat)
p = ppp(x, y, window = W)
```

Now `p` is a point pattern containing the points bounded by the polygon. To compute the distance from each point to the bounding polygon (usually called the window in `spatstat` terminology):

```
d = bdist.points(p)
```

Now `d` is a vector of distances.